# counting chars in textarea using angular

Tags: angular

I have a function to count chars in a text area:

.ts:

```
  valueChange(justification) {
    this.remainingText = 1000 - justification.length;
    console.log(this.remainingText);
  }
```

html:

```
   <div class="bx--text-area__wrapper">
      <textarea
        cols="50"
        rows="2"
        id="business-justification-textarea"
        class="bx--text-area bx--text-area--light"
        formControlName="justification"
        pInputTextArea
        (ngModelChange)="valueChange(justification)"
        maxlength="1000"
      >
      </textarea>
      <span id="count1">1000</span>
```

I get NaN on the console.log...can someone help?

Comment: `justification.lenght` in the valueChange method is misspelled, it should be `justification.length`

Comment: fixed that and still get NaN

Comment: make sure to make the subtraction only if justification is defined and type it as a number in the function parameter.
If you try to subtract something with undefined (or not a number value) you will get NaN.

Comment: @Caru Please check my answer and let me know it worked for you or not. Best wishes. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think if you want work with `ngModelChange` then you have to use `ngModel`. If you use `ngModel` your code should work. A sample code and Stackblitz link given below=>

**HTML**

```
 <div>
      <textarea  class="form-control"
                    rows="5"
                    [(ngModel)]="mydata" 
                    [name]="'something' + in" 
                    placeholder="Type..."
                    (ngModelChange)="mychange($event)"></textarea>

</div>
```

**TS:**

```
export class AppComponent {
  remainingText:number;
  mydata: string = '';

    mychange(val) {
      this.remainingText = 1000 - val.length;
      console.log(this.remainingText);
   }
}
```

[Demo code of StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ujkqzs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Answer (score 0):

The question is lacking a ton of context, making it a bit hard to answer, but as asked, the following should provide a solution for your immediate problem.

There are different ways of dealing with forms in Angular. It appears as though you are using the Reactive Forms module, but you don't include your whole form or the backing .ts file. To truly answer your question in the context you are executing it in, those files would need to be included more fully. For instance, how are you creating your form group? How are the form controls being created?, etc

`1000 - undefined` will give the answer `NaN` in JavaScript as will `1000 - {}`, with the code you have provided it is hard to tell which scenario you are facing.

> .html

```
<textarea #text (input)="checkChange(text.value)"></textarea>
```

> .ts

```
  checkChange(value: string) {
    console.log(value.length);
  }
```

Working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bppujt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) example.